# How can I create a new git project based on an old git project

Tags: git

I have been development using git after I clone from a remote repository. I have created a local branch for my own development work. 
But now I need to create a new git project from my work with a different Directory name. 
How can I create a new git project which based on the work I did, including all the commits that I did in my local branch which I have not pushed.

Thank you.

Comment: @AbeVoelker: that would just be a fork.  OP wants a whole new project based on the old one.

Answer (score 4):

Simply clone the old project and modify the remote.  Try this:

```
$ git clone old.git new.git
$ cd new.git
$ git remote add origin <remote-path>
$ git push origin
```

This will give you a complete local copy which includes history, and once the remote is modified, it will be a completely separate effort.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean when you said '<remote-path>'. How can I find out the value of <remote-path>? And until I find out the true value <remote-path>, can I have NO remote-path?

Comment: In your original repository, run this: "git remote show origin" and look at the "Fetch URL" and "Push URL".  That's where git goes to fetch and push, and is the remote.  Your new clone would need it's own remote, otherwise it's just a fork.

Comment: Yes, you can have NO remote path, but since you cloned a repository that had one, your new clone will have the same one.  So either change it, or remove it.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: Does it make sense to have something like `git remote add source-repo <old.git.path>`, so the new repository will have some reference to the original one?

Comment: @Dror That's an interesting way to document the lineage, but there is always the danger of an errant push.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: You mean doing something like `git push source-repo` from within the new repository?

Comment: @Dror: Right, once you have a remote, you could accidentally push to it, perhaps thinking it went somewhere else.  Just pointing out a risk.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: Is there some canonical way to document this kind of lineage?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was not easy for me to figure out what was involved since I am new to git. I believe the following answer might be more clear to beginners:

```
git clone <ssh|https>xyz.company.com/foo/bar.git
git remote remove origin
# then create another empty project on abc.company.com
git remote add origin https://abc.company.com/foo/bar.git
git push --force
```

What I was doing is to use some public git repositories that the original author does not bother to update or answer any questions.  The original program does not even work on the test data. So I am trying start a new project based on this non-working project.